# элементы set выводятся на экран не полностью C++

Tags: c++, ооп, множества

Цикл в конце программы выводит не все элементы содержащиеся в множестве, а только часть.
т.е должно выводиться `1 2 3 4`, а выводится `2 4`

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>

    using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
    class Set{
        private:
            set<T> a;

        public:

            Set(){}

            Set(set<T> a_){
                a= a_;
            };

    //getter setter
            set<T> getSet(){
                return a;
            }

            void setSet(set<T> sett){
                a = sett;
            }

    //overload operator
            Set<T> operator + (Set<T> s){

                Set result;
                result.a.insert(a.begin(), a.end());
                result.a.insert(s.a.begin(), s.a.end());

                return result;
            }

    };

    int main()
    {
        set<int> s;
        set<int> s2;

        s.insert(1);
        s.insert(2);

        s2.insert(2);
        s2.insert(3);
        s2.insert(4);

        Set<int> a(s);
        Set<int> b(s2);

        Set<int> c = a + b;

        for(set<int>::iterator it = c.getSet().begin(); it!=c.getSet().end(); ++it){
            cout<<(*it)<<endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: а у вас в программе есть точка с запятой после   Set(set<T> a_){
                a= a_;
            } или вы тут ошиблись?

Comment: Вам не нужно писать обёртку над сетом, если вы хотите перегрузить оператор. Его можно перегрузить и для std::set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set<T> getSet(){
    return a;
}
```

Ваш `getSet()` возвращает **копию** `a`.

Так что в строке

```
for(set<int>::iterator it = c.getSet().begin(); it!=c.getSet().end(); ++it)
```

`it = c.getSet()` создает отдельный временный `set`, который удаляется до того, как вы начинаете использовать `it` (еще до первой итерации). Читать по итератору на удаленный контейнер нельзя. 
К тому же, `it!=c.getSet().end()` тоже каждый раз создает отдельный временный `set`, а  сравнивать итераторы на два разных `set`а тоже нельзя.

Возвращайте из `getSet` ссылку на `set` (желательно на константный `set`) - тогда такой проблемы не будет.

```
const set<T> &getSet(){
    return a;
}
```

---

По хорошему, вам еще много куда нужно поставить константные ссылки, чтобы избежать лишнего копирования:

```
Set(const set<T> &a_)
...
const set<T> &getSet()
...
void setSet(const set<T> &sett)
...
Set<T> operator + (const Set<T> &s)
```

Также на некоторых методах не хватает `const`:

```
const set<T> &getSet() const
...
Set<T> operator + (const Set<T> &s) const
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше написать так(в упрощенном варианте):

```
template<typename T>
class Set {
private:
    set<T> a;
public:
    Set() {}
    Set(std::set<T> _a) :a(_a) {}
    auto begin() { return a.begin(); }
    auto end() { return a.end(); }
    //overload operator
    Set<T> operator + (Set<T> s) {
        Set<T> temp(*this);
        temp.a.insert(s.begin(), s.end());
        return temp;    
    }
};
```

Потому что, вы создаете класс множества на основе другого_стандартного класса множеств, и к тому же разрешаете доступ к нему. Это плохо влияет на смысль вашего класса. Куда лучше определить нужные свои `begin() и end()`, тогда и пользоваться удобней...

Во вторых, вы в операторе создаете обьект на основе конструктора по умолчанию, а потом начинаете вводить данные своего обьекта(this), когда у вас уже есть подходящий конструктор(где тоже нужно сразу инициализировать).  И не нужно заморачиватся с `getSet()`(об ошибке вам уже рассказали). А код ваш будет выглядеть так:

```
Set<int> a({ 1, 2 }), b({ 2, 3, 4 }),
        c = a + b;
for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, будет проще сделать таким способом(вывод):

```
for(auto l:s1)
   cout<<l<<" ";//вывод первого set
for(auto l:s2)
   cout<<l<<" ";//vtorogo
```